# Why the BorderThickness (0.5 and 1) looks like same in Border UWP?

Tags: xaml, uwp-xaml

```
<StackPanel  Spacing="2" Orientation="Vertical" Width="50">
   <Border    BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Width="50" Height="50"></Border>
   <Border    BorderThickness="0.5" BorderBrush="Black" Width="50" Height="50"></Border>
</StackPanel>
```

Both the border thickness(0.5 and 1) look like same in two borders. And when I set BorderThickness to 0.25 it won't appears. what's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the properties are working correctly. The values of **1** and **0.5** are too small, making their differences more difficult to observe. You could put your code in a Scrollviewer or a ViewBox to scale the StackPanel a little bigger, you will see the border is in different thicknesses.

I have two screen shoots here:
[image]
[image]

The second image shows what it looks like when scaling the border. And you could see that the two borders have different thicknesses.